# Registration Form Works but shows error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made a registration form. it actually works but it shows the "Failed To Register, Try Again" message.
Here's my code.

**HTML and PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];

        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("login2");

        $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$username','$password')";

        mysql_query($query);
        echo "Registered Successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo "Failed To Register, Try Again";
    }
?>
```

Comment: no way your code saves to database if this condition `if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {` is `false`

Comment: so how should i fix it?

Comment: Try `<input type="submit" value="submit" name="btn">`

Comment: When you first load the page `$_POST['btn']` **won't** be set so, yes, the *"Failed to Register"* message will appear. Also, the `mysql_` extension is obsolete - you should change to `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. You're also wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: array(0) { } Failed To Register, Try Again

Comment: @CD001 what should i set the if condition to then ?

Comment: Should you check `isset($_POST['uname'])` and `isset($_POST['pass'])` instead of `isset($_POST['btn'])` ?

Comment: @LavishSardana You sould wrap the whole POST processing echoes with `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`, so you do not echo anything if the form was not submitted yet

Comment: Your *failed* message should be an else condition of `mysqli::query()` **not** `isset($_POST['btn'])` - the fact that the button has been clicked doesn't determine with the user was created.

Comment: ... and you're storing passwords in plain text, which is a definite no-no. See: [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the post.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
// …
}
```

Also add uname and pass control.

Comment: it still says Failed

Comment: You need to put your php codes in >>> if if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
// …
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['uname']) && !empty($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        ............................
    }
    else {
        echo "Failed To Register, Try Again";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['uname']) && !empty($_POST['uname'])` - `empty()` does an `isset()` check, there's no need to use both.

Answer (score 0):

1.There is a problem with you if statement which shows failed to register on page load

2. Mysql is deprecated, use `mysqli_*`.

Here is an updated code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];

        mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysqli_select_db("login2");

        $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$username','$password')";

        $results=mysqli_query($query); 
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){ //check if inserted
            echo "Registered Successfully";
        }
        else{
            echo "Failed To Register, Try Again";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and check

```
  <?php
   if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("login2");

    $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$username','$password')";

    if(mysql_query($query))
    {
    echo "Registered Successfully";
    }

    else 
    {
    echo "Failed To Register, Try Again";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btn'])) 
    {
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];


        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "dbname";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`username`, `password `)  VALUES ('$username','$password ')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if (!$result)
        {
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        else
        {
          echo "successfully inserted";
        }
    }
?>
```